# How do I recover from accidentally removing dpkg?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

By mistake I have removed dpkg from my pc (ubuntu 16.04). When I am running apt commands, it was showing error :

```
Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

Can anyone suggest me any solution to this. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Wait - did you remove the entire package or just the binary?

Comment: How did you remove dpkg ? which command did you use ?

Answer (score 18):

To fix this, open a terminal and download the [dpkg [image: Install dpkg]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/dpkg) package:

```
# For i386:
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1_i386.deb
# For amd64
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

The versions will differ for different Ubuntu releases. If `apt-get` is still available (only `dpkg` was removed), you can still use `apt-get` to just download the appropriate version:

```
apt-get download dpkg
```

Or you can use https://packages.ubuntu.com/dpkg to get a download link for your Ubuntu release and architecture.

Extract the `data.tar.gz` file from the `.deb` file, which is actually an `ar` archive:

```
ar x dpkg_*.deb
```

Extract the package contents from `data.tar.gz` into the filesystem:

```
sudo tar xf data.tar.gz -C / .
```

**Note:** this will get just enough of `dpkg` working to let you use it. Be sure to install the `dpkg` package afterwards:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```